# PostgreSQL conditional constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in by DB

| user_id | subscription_id | subscription_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 151 | 1 | "subscribed" |
| 151 | 3 | "cancelled" |
| 151 | 4 | "cancelled" |
| 151 | 5 | "subscribed" |
| 151 | 5 | "cancelled" |

The `subscription_status` is an enum that looks like this

```
CREATE TYPE public.enum_subscription_statuses AS ENUM
    ('pending', 'subscribed', 'cancelled');
```

I am trying to create a constraint on this table .

- A user must not have two records under the same `subscription_id`
  with the `subscription_status` of 'subscribed'.
- A user can have any number of records under the same
  `subscription_id` with the `subscription_status` of 'cancelled' or
  `pending`.

e.g. the user 151 must not have two `subscribed` records for `subscription_id` 1, but can have a `cancelled` and `subscribed` record at the same time under the same `subscription_id`.

What I have achieved so far is that I created a function and placed it inside a CHECK constraint which seems to work but does not under some unknown circumstances.

```
CONSTRAINT chk_duplicate_sub CHECK (duplicate_subscription(id, user_id, subscription_id, subscription_status)
```

Is there a better way to deal with this situation ?

Comment: My PostgreSQL is _really_ rusty, but maybe something like `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX one_subscribe_only ON mytable (user_id, subscription_status)
WHERE subscription_status = 'subscribed';`?

Comment: Thanks `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX if not exists one_subscribe_only ON
 user_subscriptions (user_id,subscription_id,subscription_status)
 WHERE subscription_status = 'subscribed';` . I had no idea we could put a where clause when creating an Index. Testing this now. Thanks for the help.